# How to integrate jenkins and app center where jenkins needs to be source control system for app center?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, visual-studio-app-center, orchestration

I'm setting up a pipeline from GitHub to Jenkins and Jenkins to App Center. I don't want to connect GitHub directly to App Center as I am handling too many configurations from the same GitHub repository. To make it handle through Jenkins every configuration. Is there any orchestration tool where I can implement this functionality of continuous integration.

I don't want to use the App Center plugin in Jenkins as it is in the alpha stage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting the same adventure now. You're right - App Center plugin just doesn't have all relevant functionality. I'm going to use App Center API/CLI for activating App Center builds (Android/IOS). I.e. my Jenkins pipeline will do the following:

1. Run unit tests
2. Run SonarCloud scanner
3. Activate App Center builds